# how to combine multiple django queryset aggregates and filters

Tags: python, database, django, aggregate

I have the following problem:

```
class species(models.Model):
  pass

class question(models.Model):
  species = models.ForeignKey(species)

class answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(question)
```

Now I'd like to retrieve a queryset of species that contain **any** question that do not have **any** answers.

I mean I can get all species that have questions by using:

```
sp = species.objects.annotate(num_questions=Count('question')).filter(
    num_questions__gt=0)
```

Also I can get all questions that do not have answers using:

```
qs = question.objects.annotate(num_answers=Count('answer')).filter(
    num_answers=0)
```

But how do I combine the two things together?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can daisy-chain annotations like so:

```
sp = species.objects.annotate(num_questions=Count('question')).annotate(
          num_answers=Count('answer')).filter(num_questions__gt=0, num_answers=0)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I think you misunderstood my question. My question is not to concatenate the result lists together but to retrieve entries whose meaning is the concatenation of the two conditions.

Comment: @chaiy I have amended my answer